# django custom manager return ordering

Tags: python, django

So if I have a custom `Manager` with a custom `QuerySet`, is there a way so that everything that the `Manager`/`QuerySet` returns is ordered in a specific way **without hard coding it across all methods**?

Comment: You could use a class decorator which orders the result of each method that returns a `QuerySet`.

Comment: that would be what I mean by "hardcoding". Since I would have to do it for each method

Comment: No, the decorator would decorate all methods at once.

Comment: @SimeonVisser you would still have to put the decorator above every single method...

Comment: I was talking about a class decorator, not a method decorator. You'd decorator the class which modifies all appropriate methods of that class to return an ordered QuerySet.

Comment: @SimeonVisser and that would be able to organize by an algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ordering` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) in the `Meta` class of the Model

```
class MyModel(models.Model): 
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', ) #Or change to any other attributes.
```

This would ensure the `order by` clause of the queryset is set to order by name by default.

Comment: this is exactly what I am looking for in the short term...but in the future I would like to be able to sort by an algorithm depending on multiple column values. could I do that? something like `ordering = ('name',my_algorithm('column1','column2'))`?

Comment: but this does answer my question so I will mark it as correct

Comment: I dont believe you can do that because, these fields directly translate to columns in the database. You might have to use custom managers (you could even override the default manager) - This is a very common requirement, and managers are a widely used solution .

Comment: I am using a custom manager. That is part of my question. I can easily get the results I want, I just don't know how to order by them without hard-coding it. This works for simple things, but how would I do it for algorithms?

Comment: Good. You might want to open a bounty on this question, ifyou dont get an answer soon.